# Bien que j'aurais préféré procéder autrement

Tags: subjonctif, conjonctions, conditionnel-passé

> Je l'ai fait. Bien que j'**aurais** **préféré** procéder autrement.

Je lis partout que *bien que* exige le subjonctif. Pourtant, je pense que, dans mon contexte, ma phrase est correcte.

Il y a des exemples contenant *bien que j'aurais aimé* sur Internet, mais pas beaucoup.

Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: J'aurais spontanément dit un subjonctif plus-que-parfait : *bien que j'eusse aimé*, mais pas trouvé de références pour cet emploi.

Comment: @guillaume31 Je ne pense pas que quelqu'un écrirait de la sorte de nos jours.

Answer (score 1):

L'utilisation du subjonctif apres *bien que* a changé dans le passé et continue de changer aujourd'hui. [Cet article](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9U66xqoK0nJk.html) du bureau de traduction du gouvernement du Canada explique ces changements historiques.

Aujourd'hui on utilise le subjonctif apres *bien que* pour lier deux phrases ou une phrase exprime le contraire de ce que l’on attend logiquement de l'autre ([voir ici pour plus d'infos](https://parlez-vous-french.com/bien-que-subjonctif-ou-indicatif/)). Par exemple:

`Jean va a la plage bien qu'il pleuve.`

Par contre dans votre cas vous exprimez un conditionnel - tu aurais aimé(e) faire autrement, mais tu ne l'as pas fait. Dans ce cas on utilise le conditionnel - il n'y a pas de subjonctif du conditonnel, ce sont deux temps differents.

Le subjonctif est utilisé quand l'action est supposée, douteuse, désirée ou dépend d'un sentiment, d'un ordre aussi.

Le conditionnel est utilisé quand l'action est soumise à une condition, à une hypothèse.

[plus d'infos ici](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-102974.php)

Comment: Merci. Je n'ai pas eu le courage de lire tout le texte du 1er lien. :) Pourquoi il y a un "en" dans _tu aurais aimé(e)_ 7ème ligne dans votre réponse ? Il faudrait le supprimer.

Comment: un "e", pas un "en".